# How is it possible for one function parameter to hold two different values at the same time?

Tags: javascript

```js
function testingevent2() {
  alert("FIRST FUNCTION");
}


function testing4(someelement) {
someelement.addEventListener("click", testingevent2, false);
}

function triggering() {

  testing4(document.getElementById("testing1"));

  testing4(document.getElementById("testing2"));

}

triggering();
```

```html
<button id="testing1">first button</button>
<button id="testing2">second button</button>
```

I am struggling to understand how does this work?

When the function `triggering` is triggered, it triggers the same function twice with two different arguments. The first function defines one argument which defines the name of the button, then the second function is triggered which changes the name of the argument, which then defines another name of the event handler.

How can the parameter that holds the event handler hold two different values at the same time? Why do the function parameters not override each other? I can't wrap my head around this.

I understand how an event handler can have a parameter that holds multiple functions, since an addEventListner permits multiple functions on the same event handler, but when it comes to the actual name of the targeted element, how is that possible?

Comment: _"The first function defines one argument which defines the name of the button"_ - `someelement` is not the "name" of the button, but the button itself.

Comment: _"How can the parameter that holds the event handler hold two different values at the same time?"_ - The event handler is `testingevent2` which doesn't change in your script.

Comment: `triggering()` calls `testing4()` for both buttons. `testing4()` adds a `click` event handler (`testingevent2`) to the element that is passed as argument.

Comment: But it adds 2 different values to the parameter. How does the `element` parameter hold two different values at the same time? Why doesn't the first one override the second? First the `element` becomes `document.getElementById("testing1")`, then it becomes `document.getElementById("testing2")`. How can the parameter `element` be both at the same time?

Comment: It does not "add" a value to anything. `someelement` is just a variable that stores what ever you pass as the first/single argument to `testing4()`.

Comment: But a variable can store only one value, so how can `someelement` store two values here?

Comment: `let x = 1; console.log(x) /*1*/; x = 2; console.log(x) /*2*/; x = "foo"; console.log(x) /*foo*/;` o.O

Comment: .. yes.. and? I do not understand what you are trying to explain to me with this example. In your example `x` can store only 1 value. Either `1`, `2` OR `foo`. It does not store all 3 at the same time. Yet `someelement` stores all 2 at the same time. `someelement` is `document.getElementById("testing1")` and `document.getElementById("testing2")`  simultaneously.